AutoFS isn't mounting, but can manually mount
I can'tfigure out why autoFS mount isn't working. I can manually mount it, but can't get it to work with autofs.
edgar@Docker:~$ sudo mount 10.100.0.88:/export/Photos /mnt/nfs/Photos
    [sudo] password for edgar:
    Created symlink /run/systemd/system/remote-fs.target.wants/rpc-statd.service → /lib/systemd/system/rpc-statd.service.
    edgar@Docker:~$ sudo mount 10.100.0.88:/export/Photos /mnt/nfs/Photos
    edgar@Docker:~$ df -h
    Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev                        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
    tmpfs                       392M  1.3M  391M   1% /run
    /dev/sda1                    31G   14G   16G  48% /
    tmpfs                       2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs                       392M   48K  392M   1% /run/user/111
    tmpfs                       392M   48K  392M   1% /run/user/1000
    10.100.0.88:/export/Photos  7.3T  2.0M  7.3T   1% /mnt/nfs/Photos
    edgar@Docker:~$ ls /mnt/nfs/Photos
    'Test for photos.txt'   uploads
    edgar@Docker:~$

NFS server (open media vault)
NSF share setup at 10.100.0.88:/export/Photos
On my client (Debian)
/etc/auto.master file:
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d    
/mnt/nfs/ /etc/auto.nfs --ghost --timeout=60

/etc/auto.nfs
Photos           -fstype=nfs4     10.100.0.88:/export/Photos

My autoFS service starts up fine, but it does give a 'key "-" not found in map source(s)' error.
Googling this hasn't turned up any solutions.
 `autofs.service - Automounts filesystems on demand
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/autofs.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-06-11 00:25:56 PDT; 1min 45s ago
       Docs: man:autofs(8)
    Process: 232505 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/automount $OPTIONS --pid-file /var/run/autofs.pid >
   Main PID: 232507 (automount)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 4623)
     Memory: 3.4M
        CPU: 21ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/autofs.service
             └─232507 /usr/sbin/automount --pid-file /var/run/autofs.pid

Jun 11 00:25:56 Docker systemd[1]: Starting autofs.service - Automounts filesystems on dem>
Jun 11 00:25:56 Docker systemd[1]: Started autofs.service - Automounts filesystems on dema>
Jun 11 00:27:42 Docker automount[232507]: key "-" not found in map source(s).`

When I do an ls, I can see the director
    edgar@Docker:/mnt/nfs$ ls -l /mnt/nfs
    total 0
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jun 11 00:25 Photos

But when I try to access the NFS directory, I get an error
edgar@Docker:/mnt/nfs$ cd Photos
-bash: cd: Photos: No such file or directory

Googled extensively, attempted multiple combinations of file paths.  What am I missing?
